# Which way to recover doc2vec model more efficient?

Tags: word2vec, doc2vec

After I train a doc2vec model, I want to reuse the document vectors in another module. It seems there are two ways to implement this: **save the model** and **save doc-vectors as a dictionary**.
I just wonder which one is more memory-efficient and which one reads faster in the target module?

Comment: Please post your benchmark results. How many seconds did the first and second method take in your environment?

Comment: That's going to depend on which library you're using and other choices in your code which you haven't disclosed. As @J_H suggests, try both approaches, and compare the timings. (And also the size-on-disk, and apparent RAM usage, etc.)

Comment: Thanks guys. After some experiments, I found there is no significant difference between these two ways(At least for my dataset).

Answer (score 0):

Performance measurements matter. For an interesting number of datasets the two ways of saving will take similar time.